# How to access data in external dataframes to bring back into primary dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes below:

Zip Dataframe:

```
Zip    State
12345   NY
54321   CA
```

Locations Dataframe:

```
ID    Zip
a1   12345
b2   54321
```

TestData Dataframe:

```
   LocationID    About
   a1            Here is location a
   b2            Here is location b
```

How can I create a new column 'State' in my TestData data frame with the corresponding State data? You can use the LocationID to look up the zip in the locations df, then use the zip code to lookup the right state in the zip dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works:

```
data=pd.merge(pd.merge(TestData, Locations , right_on='ID', left_on='LocationID'),Zip ,on='Zip')
data.drop(columns=['Zip','ID'],inplace=True)
```